# Spring boot 2, jetty graceful shutdown

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jetty

I work on project using Spring boot 2.1 and embedded jetty server 9 and I faced with problem of implementing graceful shutdown mechanism. 
After discussing with team it was decided to implement next graceful shutdown politics:

1. all already incoming requests must be completed
2. all incoming requests after `SIGTERM` signal should be rejected with `503 status code`
3. health endpoint should work after `SIGTERM`
   Moreover application uses mongodb as database and if request communicate with mongo it should be completed as usual.

If I set flag `setStopAtShutdown(true)` and `setStopTimeout()` of jetty server all endpoints included `/health` starts to be unavailable but without these options they gets new requests after `SIGTERM`. 
Also application context invokes `close()` method and beans starts to destroy. In this way requests depends on mongo fails with exceptions.
Can we help me with that problem?

Comment: Im in the same boat. Did you find a solution?